# Install R package from a .git URL only if SHA has changed

Tags: r, git, devtools

I want a script to check whether an R package has changed and re-install it only if it has.  The catch it that this package is hosted on my company's Bitbucket Server, not on Bitbucket.org, so while it's public, I can't use `devtools::install_bitbucket()`, which along with `devtools::install_github()` does this checking already.  To demonstrate the behavior I want from those functions with a sample Bitbucket.org-hosted  repo, if I run:

```
install_bitbucket("dannavarro/lsr-package")
install_bitbucket("dannavarro/lsr-package")
```

The second time devtools returns:

> Skipping install of 'lsr' from a bitbucket remote, the SHA1 (0d49e988)
> has not changed since last install.   Use `force = TRUE` to force
> installation

Which is the desired behavior.  But I need to install from the `.git` URL.  In this case, that's `devtools::install_git("https://bitbucket.org/dannavarro/lsr-package.git")`.  But that doesn't check to see if the repo has changed.

Can I install from a `.git` URL with that checking behavior?  Otherwise I worry my choices are (a) unnecessarily reinstall every time the script runs, even if the package hasn't changed or (b) let the package get out of date.  I'm doing (b) right now by including in my script:

`if(!require("lsr")) install_git("https://bitbucket.org/dannavarro/lsr-package.git")`

Comment: Is it possible for you to install the R package using local file(s) obtained by pulling from the Git repository you mentioned?

Comment: yes, I can clone and pull from the repo and use `devtools::install()`.  But I'm looking for something that I can add to an .R script template to make it seamless for other users.

Comment: I view this as more of a Git problem than an R one.  I don't know enough Git to give you an exact answer, but I think you can write a bash script which will pull from Bitbucket, and if new commits are found, then update the package locally.  Then, R can act accordingly whether it should install the latest package.

Comment: Someone like @VonC or torek would be able to give you an exact solution here.  By the way, R can call external scripts, so you don't need to be boxed in simply because you are using R here.

Comment: I don't know R, nor anything about its packaging/installer tools, but if they compare SHA-1s they must keep a SHA-1 in the package itself, and a SHA-1 of the installed version somewhere else. Your task will be: (1) figure out *what* this SHA-1 is, if you want your code to co-operate with the standard installer; (2) generate that SHA-1 somewhere; and (3) replicate or repeat their installation procedure. If (big if) the SHA-1 is just `git rev-parse` output then part 1 is easy, but packaging often involves more side-bits.